# What Does sketchfab or thangs use to show model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, usdz, model-viewer

I built a site that serves as a library for a specific category of 3d models. I currently use modelviewer to show glb files of 3d models but on mobile devices the performance isn't good. Often times the page will crash and randomly reload, and the problem occurs even more when the site is loaded through the instagram web viewer which a lot of our customers use. Ive tried sites such as thangs and sketchfab and this never happens on their website so can someone tell me what they use to show model preview.

Answer (score 0):

Sketchfab uses it's own render engine with lots of optimizations applied on the fly. It's not a fork of three.js afaik.

Comment: Where do i go to find someone who can make something like this for me?

Comment: @user2002220, check out sketchfab's 3d viewer for business https://sketchfab.com/3d-viewer